# What is the meaning of this character?

Tags: php, vim, vi

I am trying to recreate an input file for an attendance software, but it won't take the input. When I opened a legacy input file with vim it showed `^K` character in light blue colour instead of a new line character shown in GUI text editors. What is the meaning of this character and how can I recreate this in PHP?

[image]

Comment: Probably a ctrl-K, which is a vertical tab character (`0x0b` or `char(11)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know which character it is, put the cursor on `^K` and press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> in normal-mode.

You will get probably:

```
<^K>  11,  Hexa 0b,  Octal 013
```

It has ascii code `11` so it might be the `vertical tab`. You can create it with this combination <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>

Comment: I actually need to create this character with a PHP script and write it to a file. I am using PyCharm as an IDE. How can I echo this character from that IDE?

Comment: Are you trying to include them inside string literals ?

Comment: I am trying to write a file like the image above with echo statement.

Comment: Maybe you can via vim emulation plugin.